# Перегрузка операторов в классе

Tags: c++, перегрузка-операторов

Всем привет! Сегодня пытался перегружать операторы, но ничего не вышло. Вот мой код:

```
    class VectorInt {
 public:
  VectorInt();
  VectorInt(size_t);
  VectorInt(int, int);
  virtual ~VectorInt();

  int &get(size_t);
  void set(size_t);
  void set(size_t, int);

  size_t getSize();

  static size_t getMaximumSize();

  VectorInt & operator=(VectorInt & obj);
  friend VectorInt operator+(VectorInt & obj1,VectorInt & obj2);

 private:
  void setAllTo(int);
  size_t size;
  int *data;
};

/* CONSTRUCTORS */

VectorInt::VectorInt() : size(1), data(new int[size]()) {}

VectorInt::VectorInt(size_t size) : size(size), data(new int[size]) 
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
      data[i] = i;
    }
}

VectorInt::VectorInt(int size, int initializer) : size(size),data(new int[size]) 
{
    setAllTo(initializer);
}

VectorInt::~VectorInt() 
{
    delete [] data;
}

/* PUBLIC METHODS */

int &VectorInt::get(size_t position) 
{
    if (position >= size)
      throw std::out_of_range("index went out of range");

    return data[position];
}

void VectorInt::set(size_t position) 
{
    if (position >= size)
      throw std::out_of_range("index went out of range");

    data[position] = 0;
}

void VectorInt::set(size_t position, int value) 
{
    if (position >= size)
      throw std::out_of_range("index went out of range");

    data[position] = value;
}

size_t VectorInt::getSize() 
{
    return size; 
}

/* STATIC METHODS */

size_t VectorInt::getMaximumSize() 
{ 
    return static_cast<size_t>(-1); 
}

/* PRIVATE METHODS*/

void VectorInt::setAllTo(int value) 
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
      data[i] = value;
    }
}

/* OPERATORS */

VectorInt operator+(VectorInt &obj1, VectorInt &obj2) 
{
    VectorInt newObj = VectorInt(obj1.getSize());

    for (size_t i = 0; i < obj1.getSize(); i++)
      newObj.set(i, obj1.get(i)+obj2.get(i));

    return newObj;
}

VectorInt & VectorInt::operator=(VectorInt & obj) 
{
    if (this != &obj) 
    {
      size = obj.size;
      delete [] data;
      data = new int[size];

      for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        data[i] = obj.data[i];

    }

    return *this;
}

int main() 
{
  VectorInt v(10);
  v.set(9);
  v.set(3, 76);

  VectorInt v2(10);
  v2.set(9);
  v2.set(3, 24);
  VectorInt v3 = v+v2;

  cout << v3.get(5);

  return 0;
}
```

В итоге v3.get(5) выводит -57662...
Хотя должен выводить 10. Я так понял, что перегрузка не сработала, не сохранились числа. Если внутри перегрузки оператора плюс вывести newObj.get(5), то выведет 10. Помогите, в чём здесь проблема?(

Comment: У вашего `VectorInt` ну *очень* странная логика. Операции делают что угодно, но только не то, что от них ожидаешь. Соответственно, понять, что должно выводиться и почему — невозможно. Использование операторов для странных операций ("сложение" векторов — это добавление пяти ко всем значениям первого вектора без участия второго вектора) ну нисколько не помогает. Приведите код к виду, когда он несёт хоть какой-то смысл.

Comment: Да, извините, я тестил просто, поправил

Comment: @iproger У вас для возвращаемого объекта `VectorInt` в операторе `+` вызывается деструктор и делается `delete [] data`.

Comment: @cybrex, ого, действительно, убрал деструктор - заработало. а почему он там вызывается? и как это предотвратить?

Comment: @iproger Уже лучше. Но всё равно много непонятного. 1) Почему при создании по размеру в массив засовываются последовательные числа, а при передаче конкретного значения — одинаковые? 2) Почему проверка индекса только сверху? 3) Почему set без значения устанавливает 0? 4) Почему при сложении не проверяется равенство размеров?

Comment: @Discord, потому что это лабораторная работа и смысла вообще никакого в коде нету, самое главное чтобы методы были и перегрузка операторов)) Я хотел сделать на скорую руку, в итоге просидел с перегрузкой целый час, потом не выдержал и сюда написал. Проверку на равенство размеров ещё не делал, мне главное чтобы работало, а уж потом проверки до кручу

Comment: Если не углублять в то, почему код не работает, а попытаться ответить на вопрос про перегрузку операторов. То [вот](http://habrahabr.ru/post/132014/) есть небольшая статья про перегрузку операторов.

Comment: с неё как раз и читал. Что же, получается надо обязательно возвращать объект без его создания? Т.е. return КОНСТРУКТОР() только так?

Comment: @iproger Возвращаясь к коду, деструктор удалять наверное не надо. А вот заменить перегрузку оператора равно на конструктор копирования стоит. Замените эту строку `VectorInt & VectorInt::operator=(VectorInt & obj)` на эту `VectorInt::VectorInt(const VectorInt& obj)`. Советую пройти по шагам или добавить printf(), чтобы стало понятно, что и когда вызывается.

Comment: да, это мне и помогло, сам только что хотел написать здесь) Нужен был конструктор с аргументом VectorInt)) Чтобы он клонировал объект. Большое спасибо!) Напишите ответ в вопросе и укажите в ответе на то что вызывается деструктор в моём коде и что нужно создать такой конструктор

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Благодаря пользователю @cybrex я понял в чём проблема. Создаваемый newObj стирается из локальной области функции (вызывается деструктор) и поэтому возвращает функция пустой объект. Я подумал, что нужно создать конструктор, который будет копировать объект. И всё удалось.
Проблему решает это:

```
VectorInt::VectorInt(const VectorInt & other) 
{
    if (this != &other) 
    {
      size = other.size;
      data = new int[size];

      for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) 
        data[i] = other.data[i];

    }
}
```